# How to generate sizes for all headers using SASS with modular scale

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins

I'm looking to create sizes for H1 through H6 using SCSS. This example assumes I've created the variables $base-size and $modular-scale. Specifically:

```
h6: $base-size * $modular-scale * 1
h5: $base-size * $modular-scale * 2
h4: $base-size * $modular-scale * 3
...
h1: $base-size * $modular-scale * 6
```

I can't figure out how to generate each of these classes using a mixin or a function (or whatever appropriate feature for this task).

so far I have:

```
@mixin make-header-size ($type, $scale) {
  .#{$type} {
    $type * $scale * (...scalar)
  }
}
```

Not sure how to complete the rest so that I can succinctly generate each of these sizes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you have a simple and small `@for` loop to generate the six heading styles with a *scale variable* that indicates the amount of px the headings grow from h6 to h1:

```
// h6 starts at $base-font-size 
// headings grow from h6 to h1 by $heading-scale
$base-font-size: 18px;
$heading-scale: 8; // amount of px headings grow from h6 to h1

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    font-size: $base-font-size + $heading-scale * (6 - $i);
  }
}
```

And a [demo codepen](https://codepen.io/fabianmebus/pen/GqQzEq) to play with it.

Comment: Can I use you code both for personal and commercial purposes ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a small function that I have created

```
$types : h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1;
$base-size : 16px;

$modular-scale : 0.5;
@each $type in $types{
  #{$type} {
    font-size : $base-size * $modular-scale;
    $modular-scale : $modular-scale + 1;
  }
}
```

See the [PEN](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/grvwdb)

I'm using this function for my personal use.

```
$headings : h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;
$font-size-base : 16px;

$font-size-upper : 36px;
$font-size-dec : 4px;
@each $heading in $headings{
  #{$heading} {
    font-size : $font-size-upper;
    font-size : ($font-size-upper / $font-size-base) + em;
  }
  $font-size-upper : $font-size-upper - $font-size-dec;
}
```

**[Check it out.](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/vKdXdw)**

Answer (score 1):

@Fabian's and @Jinu's answers are pretty good. However, I wanted my scss sizes to be context and screen-size dependent. Here's my mobile-first solution, which I arrived at by merging @Fabian, [this blog post](https://codepen.io/zgreen/post/contextual-heading-sizes-with-sass), and a `media-query` mixin. Note while you look over the code, that if your context is not in context-font, no `font-size` will be defined, so be wary of that.

```
// https://codepen.io/zgreen/post/contextual-heading-sizes-with-sass
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426884/how-to-generate-sizes-for-all-headers-using-sass-with-modular-scale
//define vars and mix-ins
$context-font: ( header: 1, section: 1, article: 0.67, footer: 0.5, aside: 0.33 ); // Make fonts change size dependent upon what context they are in
$step-size-font: 0.333333; //step size for incremental font sizes
$amplifier-font-mobile: 1.2; //convenience var to in/decrease the values of header values in one place
$amplifier-font-desktop: 1.4; //convenience var to in/decrease the values of header values in one place
$on-laptop: 800px;
$margin-heading: 0.67em 0;
@mixin media-query($device) {
    //scss mobile-first media query
    @media screen and (min-width: $device) {
         @content;
    }
}
//function to generate the actual header size
@mixin heading-size($size) {
    $context-size-computed: $size * $step-size-font;
    font-size: $context-size-computed * $amplifier-font-mobile + em;
    @include media-query($on-laptop) {
        font-size: $context-size-computed * $amplifier-font-desktop + em;
    }
}
// Apply the stylings using the vars and mix-ins
// context-free header styling
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    h#{$i} {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: $margin-heading;
    }
}
//iterate thru all the contexts in context-font, setting the header sizes in each
@each $element, $value in $context-font {
    #{$element} {
        //set header sizes 1-6
        @for $i from 1 through 6 {
            h#{$i} {
                $bigger-size-proportional-to-smaller-number: (6-$i);
                @include heading-size($bigger-size-proportional-to-smaller-number * $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Another (simpler/better?) way of getting context-specific font sizes is to use `em` font sizes, and change the font-size in your contexts. You would only do this once per context (article, section, div, whatever), and it would affect all text inside of it. That's because em is a [relative font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177923/can-anyone-explain-em-is-relative-to-the-font-size-and-is-relative-to-the-par).